# How does the time module interpret a utility?

Tags: bash, time

The man pages for the `time` module mention that the command can be used on "utilities".

```
# time usage from man pages

time [-al] [-h | -p] [-o file] utility [argument ...]
```

What is meant with "utility" here? Does it simply mean "command"?

If so, I'm confused by the following example, because there are several built-in command present: `for`, `do` and `done` (according to man pages for builtin commands). Am I right to assume that `time` interprets `for i in {1..1000}; do var=${var}foo; done;` as one "utility" here? Or does `time` interpret a "utility" as everything that follows the command if `time` doesn't appear again, else measuring a new "utility"?

```
var=; time for i in {1..1000}; do var=${var}foo; done; var=; time for i in {1..1000}; do var+=foo; done
```

Comment: If you are in `bash`, you should run `help time` to get documentation on `time`, not `man time`.